# Is this table too big?

Tags: mysql

I am developing a website in which it is important to keep track of EVERY click and EVERY impression that EACH client makes.

So I have a database which includes (among others) two tables: "clicks" and "impressions". The table "impressions" has the following structure:

```
ip int unsigned not null,
ts int unsigned not null,
main_post int unsigned not null,
side_post int unsigned not null,
PRIMARY KEY (ip,ts,main_post,side_post)
```

So there are few columns and they are all of the int type, so it is an efficient table. HOWEVER, what worries me is that this table will grow incredibly fast. With every request, five new rows will be added to this table, because there are always five side posts next to each main post. Plus, with every request, I will want to check this table to make sure I am not showing the same post again to the client.

The "clicks" table is similar, but less extreme (only one row gets added per request).

So my question is: will this be to much? Will this tables, after a few weeks or months of use, become too big to handle? And if yes, what is the best solution? Maybe starting a new table each week, or each month?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html

Comment: what do you want to do with the table?  you will be able to write to it until your disk fills...

Comment: i want to check it with every request, to make sure i am not showing the same posts to the same ips twice.. also, i want to count how many times each post was shown vs how many times it was clicked, to measure its relevance and stuff like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- How many clicks per day are you going to be handling?
- How many impressions per day?
- How long are you going to keep records?
- If a user doesn't visit for a month, do you need to know what he saw on the last visit?
- What about if a user doesn't visit for a week?

Answers to these and related questions will dictate what you need.  However, if your site becomes extremely popular and you decide you really need long histories, then the table will become unmanageable.  You have a table with 16 bytes per row; you have an index on that that is likely to cost you 20-24 bytes per row (with a bit of overhead).  Thus, for each page impression, you are going to be using 200 bytes or so in your impressions tables.  At N pages per second, you'll be using about 20×N MiB/day.

I'm not clear how you are going to structure your queries against this table to ensure that the user is not shown the same material again.  I don't know if you are thinking that IP is IP address (have you heard of IPv6?) and TS is a timestamp.  I'm not convinced that IP address is an appropriate way of tracking users (the same user may have multiple IP addresses over the course of a day - connecting from the office and from home, not to mention the coffee shop).  I'm not sure that the PK index is going to help your queries very much.

When you know how you plan to use the data, then you can decide how to store it.

My strong suspicion is that you will find this design too onerous.  The table is big enough that your queries are going to slow you down dramatically.  Yes, I believe you will need to manage the table carefully, dropping old data routinely while retaining the most recent data.

Comment: excellent answer, thanks! in response to your question, i know that tracking ips is not the best way of tracking users, but it is important to keep the website annonymous, so ips is best i can get (right?).. about the inefficiency of the PK, i was thinking if it wouldnt be more efficient to just add another column, id, and make that the primary key... is it a good idea? and yes, I will have to think it better.. maybe I can join the impressions and clicks table, by adding a column to the impressions table called "clicked"..

Comment: and yes, "ts" stands for timestamp, which is filled with the time() function of php

Comment: Adding an 'id' column to the table will not help. You're never going to use the 'id'; it merely increases each row in the 'impressions' table from about 40 bytes to about 50 bytes (counting the index data), and slows inserts down because there are now two indexes on the table. The 'inefficiency in the PK' that I'm concerned about (on your behalf) is because I'm not sure how you are going to sift the data. Using `SELECT main_post, side_post FROM impressions WHERE ip = ? AND ts >= ?` should work OK; it could be an index-only query and uses the leading columns of the index (that's good).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever archiving approach you use, it's important to normalize out any repeated data, which is generally always a good idea for OLTP data. Normalization will be helpful to the extent that you see the same main and side posts get associated.

One of these approaches might help but not knowing your data, it's hard to know.

*Main post always is associated with the same side posts (doesn't sound like it's the case). This will reduce your table to 20% of it's current size:

```
-- same impressions table minus side_post

-- table side_post
main_post int unsigned not null,
side_post int unsigned not null,
order int unsigned not null,
PRIMARY KEY (main_post,side_post)
```

*Main post is associated with a varying collection of side posts. This approach will also reduce the main table

```
-- same impressions table minus side_post and add key
main_side_post int unsigned not null

-- table side_post
main_side_post int unsigned not null --PK
-- rest of columns from table side_post above
```

Comment: I see what you did there, I will think about it, it may definitely help. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

First, if the table is InnoDB, add auto_increment as a primary key, and the rest as a unique key. In this way, writes will be sequential, instead of random, and in big table (GB in size) it's very important.

Next, partition your table on the timestamp, it will keep the table smaller, and your query for a period of data which resides on the same partition will be fast.

Next, keep in mind that you are turning your read-load into write-load! (every visitors write to the page). Better agregate data in memory and perform fewer writes. Especially when the same visitor refreshes the page - do not hit the database again. [Read here some tips](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/07/01/implementing-efficient-counters-with-mysql/)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will read them carefully. Your advice of adding an auto_increment as PK will only work for InnoDB? I think I lose nothing by using InnoDB here, right?

Comment: The advice is for storage engines with clustering on the primary key, and I know InnoDB is such. InnoDB stores the data in the order of the primary key. Since this is the only engine I'm familiar with internals, I can't tell for sure for the other ones.